# Spring integration Java DSL: How to create the JSON in the integration flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How to create the JSON in the integration flow. I want to send the JSON

```
{
   "username": "user",
   "password": "password1"
}
```

to the URL http://localhost:8051/session

My integration flow builder is:

```
.integrationFlowBuilder
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8051/session")
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).expectedResponseType(String.class))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need more context on the matter...

From big height you can just create such a JSON string statically in the `transform()`:

```
.transform(p -> "{
   \"username\": \"user\",
   \"password\": \"password1\"
}")
```

you have some POJO on the matter, it can be converted to JSON automatically via `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in the `RestTemplate`.

You also can use an `ObjectToJsonTransformer` before sending to that `Http.outboundGateway()`.

So, please, tell us more what you have so far and what kind of information you would like to have converted to the JSON.

Comment: Thanks! Static JSON String was enough this moment.